# Is there any way to disable all extensions in magento

Tags: extensions

I have several extensions on a magento site. I suspect one of them is causing a problem and I want to disable them all and then bring them back one at a time to find the problem. Is there any easier way to do this then going into app/etc/modules/* and disabling them individually?

Comment: Please check - http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/quick-tip-disable-all-local-modules-at-once/ Might help to you...

Comment: @Pravin please turn that into an answer I know it's not exactly what I'm looking for myself but it looks like the best answer so far, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dont know if helps but the only massive disable that Magento offers is only of local codepoll (app/code/local)

while going through the section on Module loading, it is revealed that we can easily disable all modules living in the local (app/code/local) namespace by editing app/etc/local.xml and setting the disable_local_modules node to true:
You can do it in your local xml:

```
<config>
     <global>
    ...
         <disable_local_modules>true</disable_local_modules>
    ...
     </global>
    ...
</config>
```

Comment: Note that this not only excludes local modules from loading but also removes `app/code/local` from the include path, so that the autoloader will not find any custom backend models, source models etc. for attributes that have been added by extensions. So, in many cases it breaks the store.

Answer (score -1):

Go to

> Admin -> System -> Configuration

and in the left on the last menu

> ADVANCED -> Advanced

and disable or enable extensions

Comment: Almost certain that only disables the HTML output for display reasons.

Comment: Extendware has an extension that can enable or disable all your extensions. also you can use CEM for this job if you can pass email verification

Comment: disable core = remove engine

Comment: @FiascoLabs `disable core = remove engine` will probably not be very helpful to people visiting this page in the future. Do you care to expand?

Comment: @sIiiS are you sure? I looked [here](http://www.extendware.com/?p=1) and it's not listed as far as I can see.

Comment: @byronyasgur Yep, since it's come up multiple times over on magentocommerce.com. There are certain modules you **DO NOT DISABLE**. **STARTING WITH MAGE CORE!!** No core, no application. In Magento, everything is a module, some are really important. And you can disable core in `Configuration->Advanced`. The only way to get back on your feet is to edit the `core_config_data` table to reenable the module.

Comment: @byronyasgur , yes they have this module but this is not free to download

Comment: @FiascoLabs thanks ... I would have thought that obvious myself ... obviously not to others. Anyway good to know.

Comment: @sIiiS thanks but I can't find it anywhere. It's not on that page is it? Looked at both page 1 and 2

Comment: @byronyasgur contact with the support

Comment: Looks like it's discontinued